# Is an abelian group of bounded exponent $\aleph_0$-categorical

Tags: gr.group-theory, model-theory

For an abelian torsion group of finite exponent, i.e. there is an integer $n$ such that $g^n=1$ for all $g\in G$, its theory appears to be $\aleph_0$-categorical by the theorem of Engeler, Ryll-Nardzewski and Svenonius. I want to confirm this fact.

Comment: Just to clarify: for you, "totient group" is a synonym for "finite abelian group"? The complete theory of any finite structure has only one model up to isomorphism. In particular, it has no infinite models. So no, it is not $\aleph_0$-categorical.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I added an answer assuming "finite order" meant "finite/bounded exponent". But perhaps it would have been good to clarify the terminology first since of course what you've said is correct!

Comment: @GabeConant Yes, I understood "finite order" to mean "finite cardinality", but I'm sure you're right that the condition I would call "finite exponent" is what the OP intended.

Comment: Why do you edit without addressing the comments? what do you mean by "finite order"?

Comment: Perhaps “totient” here is a mangling of “torsion”? (That’s a weaker property, but related.)

Comment: Yes, it is a typo and should be torsion group. Finite order means bounded order.

Comment: @hermes (1) the definition of "torsion group" is a group in which every element has bounded order. (2) the definition of "group of finite order" is just "finite group". (3) a group in which elements have finite bounded order is called "group of finite exponent".

Comment: @YCor, I modified it. One thing I am confused is that, "finite group" means a group of finite size and thus each element of it should be of finite order, right?

Comment: To clarify: (1)  I've only used "bounded order" to stay consistent with Rosenstein. "Bounded exponent" or "finite exponent" is the more standard terminology. (2) Finite groups are special cases of groups of bounded exponent. (3) Groups of bounded exponent are special cases of torsion groups, but these are not the same. A torsion group is defined as one in which every element has finite order, but there need not be a uniform finite bound on the orders. For example: $\oplus_n \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion group that does not have bounded exponent. (4) A torsion group need not be abelian.

Comment: But if the order of elements in a group is not uniformly bounded, i.e. the order can be arbitrarily large, then it is (generally) not considered as a group of finite order.

Comment: It is correct that such a group is not considered to be a group of bounded order, but it could still be a torsion group. I say all of this because you have written "A torsion group is an abelian group of bounded order." But torsion groups need not have bounded order (or be abelian).

Comment: I've rolled back your recent edit, in which you wrote "An abelian torsion group is an abelian group in which each element has finite order, i.e. there is an integer $n$ such that $g^n=1$ for all $g\in G$." The condition "$G$ is torsion" means "for all $g\in G$, there is an integer $n$ such that $g^n = 1$." There are abelian torsion groups which are not $\aleph_0$-categorical, like $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand "$G$ has finite exponent" means "there is an integer $n$ such that for all $g\in G$, $g^n = 1$." This is the type of group Gabe's answer addresses.

Comment: @hermes The question is fine as it is, and it has a good accepted answer. There's no need to change it. Looking at your profile, I don't see that you're suspended, so you should be able to ask questions now. Maybe you were previously suspended - if you were, it was for some rule violation, not because someone thought this was a bad question.

Comment: I have to pay close attention to questions with lower upvotes. Since this question has one upvote and one downvote, I guess it is considered a bad question. I am still banned to ask questions on this site which can not be seen from the profile. I do not have any rule violation and so the ban must be due to some questions I have asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a theorem of Rosenstein from the paper *[$\aleph_0$-categoricity of groups](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X03328/1-s2.0-0021869373900926/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEO7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHZ04EYzAqky510u1oBygW1At1j7x%2B5r3OV5TdolDRWPAiEA5ivtoZxXofL7aNGuQV2i3JLgT5h2rBKfjeb3thSqnpMqvQMIlv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDL%2BDlH2eCwH7WlCJGSqRA%2BswnBQPE5BKYbaRV2PyQ4aGGv5yanbZr%2BNsSeoh7bzkFnaCOBldZUi3QTAbvATcNeQ%2B5U3nhtK%2Bk1T9XAPK01KK%2BJz2CI4%2BbO9MexuSIFM51tIpIw4HGAlqKh0Vivde20HjMftCSsu2SnHVpAm%2F9Qmq4IA%2Bl0y9SCUpRAjEnHIv6KMXDK%2Ba8EtBTjKgEy%2FDr3BA3Yl9V6LgdQ%2B1nCLnIHTwU0OEzLH2NHg9U4%2FzAm1H%2Bijj0P1ZzH2iE%2FnhNrtLDFijudB0TBDdRvlHPuS%2BzXcG3GYwxpvXkAQOCHjSHrcXOSpq5U6H%2BIdGU5KRSHT3NQrWg8SrqmfSTHfgexwzaTzjIug7aCjPxcfwjM4pISJs5l0gIYxO7mvYRspQSAQ6AEUheMjA%2B7X4lA4LZkDCUqFiAeAj3XuwGBcFSW0gl%2FITLqj%2FlBLLm1pFYnCp5%2BJBbCwBtjNoECW%2Br1nT4siVY5Hw356%2ByI11jZ1ki3nddALe%2FJKftuQfZda%2F%2BbAww1vUFfgsXO3Act4WTwuq7w%2FyTEnLMInBuPgFOusBxl1bgaKdr6n6asqTO6i7L4enprFVlt50OxnckSPq8FXKPtuF%2FPCv6in%2BEFAruPqy4L6otfG7XRusxiYl6Nal6yWgomSVkqkj8CNf67%2BfIC4yA2voGnyWT1RbS5Ii8zerGCWNVKJFKQTdSUscpT%2B0VN06tAPKHux7QrfSx%2Fav%2BNiIfWJ%2Bx1hOEg7lNGgXOqwB2zZ0dHdddrgdpGtSJ%2Bj6qO%2F9vC%2BAbqFsNLUk9jfa5DQefkhswtRZqEuWn9E4C2qalYDkpJvSqFtOE0jfWA8ITQXZoLaGmAc%2F7v4FKEhKkFHOma0mYkEmfX92rQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200714T223940Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYTHJVZKX3%2F20200714%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a7ed2b321ded4639a7ae34495eb16ebd013b44f97aabdadd8add96cb93031b9b&hash=379d723ce72c0430fb0fccaa6082460b05aa68b6845798676ca4b968e3ec62aa&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021869373900926&tid=spdf-987313b5-1422-4f5b-a9e4-054d8aa1e05a&sid=e191fc0874983346178b6c043a894d10dbc8gxrqa&type=client)*. But note that he uses the terminology *bounded order* rather than *finite exponent*.

I say that a group is *$\aleph_0$-categorical* if its complete theory in the language of groups is $\aleph_0$-categorical (i.e., has a unique countable model).

It is not hard to show that an $\aleph_0$-categorical group has finite exponent. This is also Theorem 1 of Rosenstein's paper. Theorem 2 of his paper provides a converse for abelian groups. So we have:

> **Theorem.** (Rosenstein 1971)
> An infinite abelian group is $\aleph_0$-categorical if and only if it has finite exponent.

---

**Appendix.** The discussion below has inspired me to add some discussion of the proof of theorems, and some other remarks. The theorem above comes from two results in Rosenstein's paper.

**Theorem 1.** *An $\aleph_0$-categorical group has finite exponent.*

*Proof.* Rosenstein uses the following fact, due to Ryll-Nardzewski/Enegler/Svenonius independently.

> A countably infinite structure $M$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical if and only if for all $m>0$, the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ on $M^m$ has finitely many orbits.

Now suppose $\operatorname{Th}(G)$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical. We may assume $G$ is countable. Since elements of distinct orders are in distinct orbits of the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ on $G$, there is a uniform bound on the orders of torsion elements in $G$. Moreover, $G$ has no elements of infinite order since, if $g$ were such then $(g,g^n)$  for varying $n$ would be in distinct orbits in the action on $G^2$.

**Theorem 2.** *An infinite abelian group of finite exponent is $\aleph_0$-categorical.*

See Rosenstein's paper. The main tool is a structure theorem for abelian groups of finite exponent as direct sums of cyclic groups. This is apparently called Prufer's First Theorem.

Some remarks:

1. By YCor's comment about $\mathbb{Q}^{(\omega)}$, one cannot prove Theorem 1 by considering only orbits of singletons. ($\mathbb{Q}$ works also.)
2. It is easier to prove that an $\aleph_0$-categorical *torsion* group $G$ has finite exponent. Indeed, if not then by compactness/DLS there is a countable model of $\operatorname{Th}(G)$ with an element of infinite order, which cannot be $G$. But if $G$ is not a torsion group, I don't see a quick way to avoid Ryll-Nardzewski or Omitting Types of some kind (although one can substitute other facts that use these results, e.g., in an $\aleph_0$-categorical structure, the algebraic closure of a finite set is finite).
3. An $\aleph_0$-categorical group need not be abelian. An example is the countably infinite extraspecial $p$-group (see Definition 5.15 [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00657716v2/document)). On the other hand, there are many results in model theory along the lines of "$\aleph_0$-categorical plus some model-theoretic property" implies some abelian-like structure. For example, Bauer, Cherlin, and Macintyre showed that an $\aleph_0$-categorical superstable group is abelian-by-finite.
4. An infinite group of finite exponent need not be $\aleph_0$-categorical. For example, take an infinite finitely generated group of finite exponent (like a Tarski monster). Indeed, by the more general result about algebraic closure stated above, if $G$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical then any finite subset of $G$ generates a finite subgroup.

Comment: In fact, a google search for "totient group" turns up this question as the only usage of that phrase in a mathematical context.

Comment: @Alex On the page 2 "badlands" of Google searches I found it used in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1968334.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A7845a21f4dc4e8bacf228225f4fac92e). I think that there author actually does mean the group of units mod $n$, which supports your interpretation. I'm now also quite intrigued by [this](http://totientgroup.com/index.html).

Comment: Haha. I found that paper too, but I considered "the totient group of $n$" to be a different usage than "totient group" as a general concept (certainly not every finite abelian group is the group of units mod $n$ for some $n$).

Comment: Actually, that every abelian group of bounded exponent is $\aleph_0$-categorical is pretty easy (and probably straightforward from Szmielew); I guess the bulk of Rosenstein's theorem is the reverse direction.

Comment: @YCor His proof of Thm2 is definitely longer, for whatever that's worth. But yes I agree. Anyway, in light of all these comments I'm definitely less sure what the original intention of the question was. Hopefully it will be clarified.

Comment: For the other direction: If $G$ has elements of arbitrarily large finite order then there are infinitely many orbits of singletons. If $G$ has an element $g$ of infinite order then $(g,g^n)$ for varying $n$ yield infinitely many orbits of pairs.

Comment: I thought categoricity was a property of theories, not structures. I'm guessing that people are saying "$\aleph_0$-categorical sructure" when then mean "structure whose elementary theory is $\aleph_0$-categorical".

Comment: @GabeConant what's an orbit of singleton? for the group $\mathbf{Q}^{(\omega)}$ the automorphism group acts transitively on nonzero elements.

Comment: @bof what's the meaning for a noncomplete theory to be $\aleph_0$-categorical? (I didn't find the answer)

Comment: @YCor I never studied logic seriously so my knowledge of the subject is rather scattershot, but I think I know that one. A theory $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical if all models of $T$ of cardinality $\kappa$ are isomorphic. Examples: theory of plain sets with no additional structure; theory of dense linear orders with (or without) top and bottom elements; theory of atomless Boolean algebras. Hmm. I guess the theory of the random infinite graph is another one.

Comment: @YCor I’m talking about the action of $Aut(G)$ on $G^m$ for varying $m$. $\aleph_0$-categoricity is equivalent to those actions having finitely many orbits for all $m$. “Singleton” and “pair” refers to $m=1$ and $m=2$. In the first case elements of different orders must be in different orbits. One can also think of $m$-types over $\emptyset$ rather than orbits of $m$-tuples.

Comment: @bof Yes you are correct it’s a property of the theory. But it’s common for people to say that a structure has a property when they mean its complete theory does. E.g. “$M$ is stable” means “$Th(M)$ is stable.”

Comment: @Emil Your argument is doesn't cover the case that $G$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Fair enough. --

Comment: @bof, $\aleph_0$-categorical structure is defined as a structure of size $\aleph_0$ whose theory is $\aleph_0$-categorical .

Comment: @hermes According to that definition, isn't the answer to your question trivially "no", since an Abelian group of bounded exponent may be uncountable or finite? Did you mean to say "is a countably infinite Abelian group of bounded exponent $\aleph_0$-categorical?

Comment: @bof, I mean it is countable because $ℵ_0$-categorical is countable.

Comment: I don't think Theorem B is correct as stated: $G=C_4\times C_2^{(\omega)}$ and $H=C_4^2\times C_2^{(\omega)}$ both have infinitely many elements of orders 2 and 4, but they are not isomorphic: $G/G_2\simeq C_2$ and $H/H_2\simeq C_2^2$, where $G_2=\{g\in G:g^2=1\}$.

Comment: FWIW, the number (finite or infinite) $n$ of copies of $C_{p^k}$ in the decomposition of $G$ to prime power cyclic groups is given by $G_{p^k}/(G_{p^{k-1}}(G^p\cap G_{p^k}))\simeq C_p^{(n)}$ if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks @Emil I will make some edits